# Getting the value in html.textboxfor()?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this in my aspx:

```
 <div class="col2-input" id="Launch-Height-value">
  <input type="hidden" name="Launch-Height" id="Launch-Height" value="<%: Model.LaunchHeight %>" />
  <%:  Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LaunchHeight) %>
</div>
<div class="col3">
  <div id="save-launch-height">
    <a href="javascript:saveLaunchHeight();" class="button">Save</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

saveLaunchHeight:

```
   function saveLaunchHeight() {
    $("#Launch-Height").val($("#Launch-Height").val());
    updateSaveButtons();
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("UpdateLaunchHeight", "Scorm", new { area = "Admin" }) %>?scormModuleId=<%: Model.ScormModuleId %>&value=" + $("#Launch-Height").val(), function (data) {
        alert($("#Launch-Height").val($("#Launch-Height").val()));
   });
 }
```

then updateSaveButtons:

```
  function updateSaveButtons() {
  if ($("#LaunchWidth").val() != $("#PassScoreHidden").val())
      $("#save-pass-score-button").show();
   }
```

in the view i can change the width value and click save and it updates the html.textboxfor, but that is about it...

then the httpget in the controller

```
 [HttpGet]
[NoCache]
public JsonResult UpdateLaunchWidth(int scormModuleId, short value)
{
    if (value > 0)
    {
        var module = ZincService.ScormService.GetScormModule(scormModuleId);
        if (module != null)
        {
            try
            {
                module.LaunchWidth = value;
                ZincService.ScormService.UpdateScormModuleSettings(module);
                ZincService.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex, "Error setting new value for LaunchWidth property for scorm module with Id " + scormModuleId);
                return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
            return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this does not save my new value. I did not write this code so cant change too much on how it works.. If i can just get the value in the html.textboxfor...
please help?

thanks

Comment: not too worry, i sorted it thanks